# Connect ADSL modem SMC7904WBRA-N to CISCO RV082

Tags: bridge, adsl, cisco-vpn

I have a SMC7904WBRA-N ADSL modem/router that connects to the internet with a static IP given by the provider.

I've received a RV082 to create a VPN connection which is having problems to connect to the remote VPN Server. After many tries we deduced that the SMC7904WBRA-N is being problematic with the NAT and I have been suggested to put the SMC router into the appropriate DSL bridging mode so the RV082 gets direct access to internet with the static IP.

Can you give me any hints on how could this be done? Which mode is that?

Comment: Why are people voting to close this? SMB gear is not off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

This is something your DSL provider should be able to answer, as I'm guessing that they were the ones who delivered the modem in the first place. It's not an uncommon question for them either.